# jquery evaluating object with val()

Tags: jquery

val() doesn't seem to be working like i expected it to, heres my code:

```
    var counter = 0;
$("input:not([type=hidden])").each(function(index, obj){
    if($(obj).val() != "" || $(obj).val() !=  "XXX-X-XX-XXXXXX-X")
    {
        console.log($(obj).val());
        counter++;
        return false;
    }
});
```

problem being i keep seeing an empty string ("") in the console even when it should only evaluate when its not "". been on this for ages, any help is appreciated :)

Comment: You’re making sure that either x is not an empty string or x is not `"XXX-X-XX-XXXXXX-X"`. One of these will always be true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your if statement is still `true` because "" !== "XXX-X-XX-XXXXXX-X". Changing your || to && will fix this logic bug

Comment: wow i feel like an idiot :P i think its time i take a break for a while. Thank you! :)